# Display Web Interface by entering IP of LAN computer

Tags: c#, web-services, tcp, client, ip

So basically, I have a software which can consist of 1 to many clients and 1 to many servers. I want to create a web interface for my server side software. A client should be able to get their server machine's IP address and enter it into a web browser. It will then display our web interface populated with different buttons which interact with the server side software.

Generally, we are trying replicate the technology of connecting to a wireless router. For example, with the IP of your router, you are able to enter it into a browser like Chrome and it will display your wireless router's configuration screen where you can change the configurations of your router.

Would I need to use a service like IIS or Apache to do something like this?

If someone can please help me get into the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

I thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the user to access your interface through a web browser then yes, you will need an HTTP server to serve your interface. Apache and IIS can be used here.

As you tagged your question with the [C#] tag, I think you will write your application using .NET technologies so IIS will be your server of choice.

Concerning using the IP address to access your server, it's not an issue as long as you know the IP and you can reach it. It the server is behind a router, you may have to play a little with the NAT configuration.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer me, but I am still a little confused. How I go about about installing and configuring IIS for our specific purpose?

Comment: You will find a lot of ressources about IIS installation on MS official website: http://learn.iis.net/

Comment: And BTW, you may find more help about IIS installation on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) website...

Comment: Alright thank you very much, I will look at both of these websites and see what I can learn

Comment: Well, actually my problem isn't exactly resolved. I can't figure out how to use my already coded Web Application to IIS and make it work.

Comment: You may have a look at this site so: [Deploying Your Site Using Visual Studio](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/Deploying-Your-Site-Using-Visual-Studio-cs).